# Installing an SFTP server on Windows using "sshd.exe install" does not work

Tags: windows, powershell, openssh, sftp

I am trying to install an SFTP server on my Windows 10 Machine and I am following this tutorial: http://woshub.com/installing-sftp-ssh-ftp-server-on-windows-server-2012-r2/.

I have already generated the keys and now I am inputting this command on Windows PowerShell (which I run as administrator), but I get an error which I don't know how to fix:

```
PS C:\OpenSSH-Win64\OpenSSH-Win64> .\sshd.exe install
__PROGRAMDATA__\ssh/sshd_config: No such file or directory
```

I tried to copy the file `sshd_config` inside the `ProgramData\SSH` folder but then I got this:

```
PS C:\OpenSSH-Win64\OpenSSH-Win64> .\sshd.exe install
Extra argument install.
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this? I appreciate any help, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*That article is probably rather dated. Though I actually do not think that there was ever a version of Win32-OpenSSH that used that command to install. So the article is possibly even completely wrong.*

---

Anyway, check:

- [Official installation guide](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) or
- *my* article on [Installing OpenSSH on Windows](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server#windows_older).

Both show that the command to use is:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File install-sshd.ps1
```